# Why am I getting """j"" is not valid at the start of a code block." here?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, view

I've got this in my Index.cshtml (View) code:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <label class="control-label">Delivery Performance (report spans a number of days)</label>
    <br>
    <label>From</label>
    <select>
        @for (int i = 1; i <= @maxDaysBackForDeliveryPerformance; i++)
        {
            <option id="selItem_@(i) value=@"i">@i</option>
        }
    </select>
    <label>days back</label>
    <br>
    <label>To</label>
    <select>
        @for (int j = 1; j <= @maxDaysBackForDeliveryPerformance; j++)
        {
            <option id="selItem_@(j) value=@"j">@j</option>
        }
    </select>
    <label>days back</label>
    <br>
    <button id="btnTestDeliveryPerformanceSettings">Test Settings</button>
</div>
```

This ran fine (prior to adding the part at the bottom):

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <label class="control-label">Delivery Performance (report spans a number of days)</label>
    <br>
    <label>From</label>
    <select>
        @for (int i = 1; i <= @maxDaysBackForDeliveryPerformance; i++)
        {
            <option id="selItem_@(i) value=@"i">@i</option>
        }
    </select>
    <label>days back</label>
</div>
```

...but when I added the essentially identical code:

```
<br>
<label>To</label>
<select>
    @for (int j = 1; j <= @maxDaysBackForDeliveryPerformance; j++)
    {
        <option id="selItem_@(j) value=@"j">@j</option>
    }
</select>
<label>days back</label>
<br>
<button id="btnTestDeliveryPerformanceSettings">Test Settings</button>
```

...it fails with that Parser Error. I don't see the "j" at the start of the code block that it sees?

This is the line (193) it implicates:

```
<option id="selItem_@(j) value=@"j">@j</option>
```

What has gone haywire/south?

### UPDATE

Shifting the @ sign inside the quotes like so:

```
<option id="selItem_@(j) value="@j">@j</option>
```

...moved the err msg up two lines; now it's complaining about this line:

```
@for (int j = 1; j <= @maxDaysBackForDeliveryPerformance; j++)
```

...saying that, "*The for block is missing a closing "}" character.  Make sure you have a matching "}" character for all the "{" characters within this block, and that none of the "}" characters are being interpreted as markup.*"

Comment: It should be `id="selItem_@(j)" value="@j"`

Comment: Then why did the one for "i" work?

Comment: It doesn't - you have mis-matched quotes and that one needs to be corrected as well. (But why are you not using the `DropDownListFor()` method to generate your select?)

Comment: It's been aeons since I worked with this technology; thanks for the "DropDownListFor()" reminder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not properly wrapping the `Id` and `value` attribute values in quotes.

wrap your variable in `""` or `''`.

```
@for (int i = 1; i <= maxDaysBackForDeliveryPerformance; i++)
{
     <option id="selItem_@(i)" value="@i">@i</option>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seprate Id and Value attirbute

Id = "Some" Value = "Another"